# calculate time for Duty Hrs & OverTime Hrs in java

Tags: java, sql, string, jdbc, time

i have time string which i get from jtextfield as intime and second string which i get from database want to calculate totoal duty hrs and OverTime hrs  and send it to the database  in java

```
 stm=con.createStatement();rs = stm.executeQuery("Select * from InOut where  Token_No='"+jTextField1.getText()+"'");
 if(rs.next())
  { 
   String intime = rs.getString("In_Time");JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"IN Time is '"+intime+"'"+"'");
   String outtime = jTextField2.getText();
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Out Time is '"+outtime+"'"+"'");
```

Please guide....

Comment: what is the format of time coming from database as well as getting from text field.

Comment: I have set time format is as hh:mm:ss

Comment: Your requirement is a bit vague, but in short you need a start and end time. Im expecting you are trying to see how long a person has been working in a system (Hours spent logged in ?)

Comment: Actually I want to see a person's worked time

Comment: @Sandee1983 Can you focus your question? Is it that you have a start time and a stop time and you want to calculate the elapsed time between them as a number of hours? Is your question about the database? Or is the question about working with date-time values in Java? Try to boil down the question to one sentence.

Comment: i found solution for said problems thank you very much for helping me